# Outlook integration - what does it mean that "Recurring Events are available in Salesforce Classic only"

Tags: outlook, salesforce-outlook-sync

The problem is that recurring calendar events created in outlook do not appear in the salesforce calendar (non-recurring events are fine).

I found [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=outlookcrm_sync_recurring_events.htm&type=5) which says "Recurring Events are available in Salesforce Classic only"

What does this mean? If I switch to classic should I be able to see the events? I tried to look for the events in classic but I could not even find an event or a calendar object.

Comment: What's your setup? You've activated Lightning in Salesforce, but not using Lightning for Outlook?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves yes, we are using lightning for outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document link is talking about Salesforce for Outlook which is different than Lightning for Outlook.

Recurring event syncing was released in Spring 19 as noted in the release notes:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_lightning_sync_series_ga.htm

[image]

First, I would look at your sync settings in Salesforce to make sure you're syncing from Outlook to Salesforce (Setup --> Outlook Configurations --> Click on your configuration for your profile **(users' profile or users themselves need to be explicitly added under a configuration)**.

[image]

[image]

Second, I would check that you've enabled recurring tasks in Lightning Experience. Setup --> Activity Settings --> "Enable Creation of Recurring Tasks".

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_recurring_tasks_lex.htm&type=5

[image]

---

There's also a separate way to sync events through Microsoft Exchange. Setup --> Outlook Integration and Sync. This has separate limitations and is probably why your users are able to sync events without being in a outlook configuration. The reason they can't do recurring events is because that's a limitation of using "Lightning Sync" (Exchange to Salesforce) as noted in the documentation

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=productivity_sync_exchange_admin_overview.htm&type=5
[image]

**To summarize:**

Lightning for outlook has two different setups for syncing events.

1. typical Outlook --> Salesforce using "Outlook Configurations". Users or their profile have to be assigned to a configuration. This can do recurring events and is what's mentioned when describing LFO and event syncing.
2. Using "Lightning Sync" which lets users sync events between Microsoft Exchange and Salesforce. This can not do recurring events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the settings you described, we are syncing outlook to salesforce and recurring tasks are enabled.

Comment: Are the profiles added to that configuration under "Assigned Users and Profile"? Specifically, your profile if you're testing?

Comment: No, there is only a single user assigned, but we only have one config. Is it possible for users to have no config, if they aren't assigned to the only existing one?

Comment: Yes. They need to be assigned either explicitly as users or through profile.

Comment: Is it possible non-recurring events have been syncing some other way then, since those are working correctly?

Comment: Are you syncing through Microsoft Exchange? Setup --> Outlook Integration and Sync. Otherwise, I could be mistaken as I don't have a current setup utilizing the events part of LFO to really test it out.

Comment: Setup --> Outlook Integration and Sync is enabled, yes.

Comment: I added another section in an edit. That's how they're currently syncing events. Exchange to Salesforce has a limitation of not being able to do recurring events as noted in the docs. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=productivity_sync_exchange_admin_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you so much. I think my failure to distinguish these features was the source of confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100542/discussion-between-kris-goncalves-and-vertical-sunlight).